# Adding a fragment with custom view to sliding navigation

Tags: android

I want to have a navigation drawer but with arbitrary views inside of it. Not only list items. Is it possible? What library should I use to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it possible?"
Ans: **YES**

"What library should I use to implement this?"

Ans: **Navigation Drawer in android sdk will work perfectly.**

Official Doc: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

`DrawerLayout`class is a child class of `ViewGroup`, this means it has all the features of a view group. We are not restricted to only Listview but we can add any type of view inside `DrawerLayout`.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Content of drawer"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#12D"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Custom view"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this hope it will help you in understanding navigation view.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer